# BadImageFormatException when using IEnumerable and Multi Inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, yield, il

Today I got a very weird problem which I was able to solve, but I still do not understand why this is happening. This is the scenario:

### EDIT

I changed the scenario to be much simpler:
I have a Program that executes the code, and 2 Importers, a base class with a generic type and another class (ImplementingImporter) that just calls the base method and iterates over it. 
This is the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace IEnumeratorLoadProblem {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            var importer = new ImplementingImporter();
            try {
                var data = importer.GetData().ToArray();
            } catch (BadImageFormatException ex) {                
                Console.WriteLine("Why does this fail? " + ex.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class BaseClassImporter<T> {

        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetData() {
            yield break;
        }
    }

    class ImplementingImporter : BaseClassImporter<int> {
        public override IEnumerable<int> GetData() {
            // iterating seems to cause the problem
            foreach(var dataByBaseImpl in base.GetData()) {
                yield return dataByBaseImpl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program
>   with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

When I change the code from the used importer to it **works**:

```
class ImplementingImporter : BaseClassImporter<int> {
    protected override IEnumerable<int> GetData() {
        return base.GetData();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I was not able to look at the generated IL Code, because both ILSpy and Reflector.NET (Version 6) displayed an internal error (I think it was anArgumentOutOfRangeException). I was afraid to use ildasm, so I did not try to look at the IL Code directly.

I guess it has something to do with the generated IL code but I cannot think of the scenario that is causing the Problem.

Any ideas what is happening here?
If the scenario is not clear enough please leave a comment and I will try to make it clearer.

### EDIT:

Used .NET version: 4.0. The Application is a ConsoleApplication using VS 2010 SP1.
Build Platform target is AnyCPu, but the problem also shows up when using x86.
My machine has a 64 bit System (Windows 7).
The exception also occurs when using .NET 4.0 client profile.

The example is a single project, no external/unmanaged libraries are used, therefore only the suggested problems (e.g. referencing a 32 bit assembly when running 64 bit) should not occur.

Comment: This exception is usually when you are in a 32/64 bit process trying to load DLLs of the other "bitness". A process can only target one platform, and once chosen only DLLs of the same platform can be loaded (once 32 bit, always 32 bit - same for 64 bit). Make sure the target platform on the DLLs you are building are all the same, either x86/x64 explicitly (but all the same) or AnyCPU for implicitly choosing the bitness.

Comment: This was my first guess too, so I checked the options and created a single project to reproduce the problem (I guess it should not be a build problem when everything is within a single assembly). I am going to add some other info's about used .NET version etc. in the question

Comment: The same rule is applied to other third party managed and unmanaged DLLs that run in-process also.

Comment: The solution only contains a single project and does not include external dll's. It should be possible to copy the given scenario into one file and run it. Maybe I can simplify the scenario.

Comment: I updated the example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to guess it has something to do with the code emitted by the compiler to support the `yield` keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with the `yield return` statement:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/677532/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-exception-from-hresult-0x8007000b#details

They state it is fixed in VS2012 (or "the version after VS 2010").

I am running a console application targeting .NET Framework 4 using VS2010 SP1 and can confirm I get the same error as you. I do not have a VS2012 install available to try this with.

A similar-ish question has been asked here:

[Iterator blocks and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432821/iterator-blocks-and-inheritance)

Another suspiciously similar example (this time with async, but triggered on `MoveNext` again):

[C#5 AsyncCtp BadImageFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283644/c5-asyncctp-badimageformatexception)

Other resources:

- [German connect entry.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757873/issue-yield-if-generic-base-class-c-net4-0)
- [Linked MSFT forum post from above](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/dotnetframeworkde/thread/26f429bb-a754-4176-8ac2-b476996e7618/) (use translate).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I still can reproduce the bug using the code from connect.microsoft.com. I guess microsoft has a different interpretation of fixed than I do.

Comment: @BernhardKircher Yeah I can reproduce it too.

Comment: @BernhardKircher Found another odd occurrence of it, this time with async, but still with generated code.

Comment: @BernhardKircher: They say it's fixed in builds _after_ VS2010, so you may need to try VS2012 to actually get the fix.

Comment: @JasonWilliams I didn't actually spot that, I've amended my answer.

Comment: +1 I've wasted a few hours on it... Finally someone pointed the real reason out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your projects use the same compilation option (AnyCPU, x86, or x64).

If you use any external dlls, make sure they are compatible (i.e. 32-bit on an x86 machine, and 64-bit on an x64 machine).

If you want to use 32 bit dlls on an x64 machine, then you will need to set your main .exe to compile as "x86" rather than "Any CPU" - that will force the entire app to run as a 32-bit process on a 64-bit PC. (If you don't do this, your exe will be JIT compiled as a 64-bit app on an x64 machine, and then try to call your 32-bit dll, which will throw the exception you are getting)

Comment: The solution only contains a single project and does not include external dll's. It should be possible to copy the given scenario into one file and run it. Maybe I can simplify the scenario...